# Getting wrong answer to Project Euler #81

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, shortest-path, dijkstra

Problem 81:
https://projecteuler.net/problem=81
tldr: Find the minimal path sum from the top left to the bottom right by only moving right and down in matrix.txt,a text file containing an 80 by 80 matrix.

It seems like a shortest path problem in a weighted edge acyclic graph and I applied dijkstra's algorithm to it. I am getting correct answer to some test cases i tried and i am getting the wrong answer for the Problem.

Edit: for some reason, when i put comments in the code, it formats it to bold and ruins the code formating so i ll just put them up here.

Comments:

ar contains the array and sp is a memo containing all shortest paths
u[0] is number and u[1]=i and u[2]=j
Q is a priority queue, each element has (value,pos x, pos y)
sp is a dict which stores the shortest paths to (value, pos x, pos y) 
S stores (value,pos x, pos y) of items which we already know shortest paths to

My code:

```
import numpy as np


def readfile(filename):
    file = open(filename,"r")
    ar=np.zeros((80,80))
    sp={}
    for i in range(80):
        l=file.readline()
        line=l.split(',')
        for j in range(80):
            ar[i][j]=int(line[j])
            sp[(int(line[j]),i,j)]=10000000
    return ar,sp

def extract_min():
    min_n,i,j=100000,-1,-1
    for n in Q:
        if n[0]<min_n:
            min_n=n[0]
            i=n[1]
            j=n[2]
    return min_n,i,j

def adj(u):

    try: a,i,j=(ar[u[1]][u[2]+1],u[1],u[2]+1)
    except:a,i,j=-1,-1,-1
    try: b,k,m=(ar[u[1]+1][u[2]],u[1]+1,u[2])
    except:b,k,m=-1,-1,-1
    return ((a,i,j),(b,k,m))

def relax(u,v):

    if sp[v]>sp[u]+v[0]:
        sp[v]=sp[u]+v[0]
        parent[v]=u

def dijkstra():

    Q.append(source)
    S=[]
    while len(Q)!=0:
        u=extract_min()
        Q.remove(u)
        S.append(u)
        for v in adj(u):
            if v not in Q and v not in S and v[0]!=-1:
                relax(u,v)
                Q.append(v)

ar,sp=readfile("p081_matrix.txt")
source=(ar[0][0],0,0)
dest=(ar[79][79],79,79)
sp[source]=source[0]
Q=[]
parent={}
dijkstra()
print(sp[dest])
```

Comment: I have looked at the problem definition and solved it with dynamic programming. I am having a difficult time following your code with your variable names. I am not sure why you would ever have a `try` `except` block in such a solution. I don't think Dijkstra's algorithm is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

As I commented, I don't think Dijkstra's algorithm is the best approach, but I have updated your code to get it to work. I have added comments to the lines that I have modified. The changes are of two types:

1. Lines commented with the word 'updated' in lower case represents minor changes that only affect performance, such as replacing the use of a list with a set or an improvement in style such as getting rid of the need for a try-except block.
2. Lines commented with the word 'UPDATED' in upper case represents the actual problem that needed to be corrected.
3. I removed my Dijkstra implementation as it was not useful in helping you find what was wrong with your program. However, consider this: The way you estimate the current distance to location x, y is with a dictionary whose key is a tuple `(a, x, y)` with `a` being the contents of the array at location array[x, y] and whose value is the distance. Why not just use a two dimensional array indexed by x and y whose value is the distance, which is what I had used?

The corrected code:

```
import numpy as np


def readfile(filename):
    file = open(filename,"r")
    ar=np.zeros((80,80), dtype=np.int32) #updated: use an integer type
    sp={}
    for i in range(80):
        l=file.readline()
        line=l.split(',')
        for j in range(80):
            ar[i][j]=int(line[j])
            sp[(int(line[j]),i,j)]=10000000
    return ar,sp

def extract_min():
    min_n,i,j=100000,-1,-1
    for n in Q:
        if n[0]<min_n:
            min_n=n[0]
            i=n[1]
            j=n[2]
    return min_n,i,j

def adj(u): #updated: new replacement that does not use try/except

    l = []
    row = u[1]
    col = u[2]
    if row < 79:
        l.append((ar[row+1][col], row+1, col))
    if col < 79:
        l.append((ar[row][col+1], row, col+1))
    return l

def relax(u,v):

    if sp[v]>sp[u]+v[0]:
        sp[v]=sp[u]+v[0]
        parent[v]=u
        return True # UPDATED
    return False #UPDATED

def dijkstra():

    Q.add(source) #updated
    #S=[] #UPDATED
    while len(Q)!=0:
        u=extract_min()
        Q.remove(u)
        #S.add(u) #UPDATED
        for v in adj(u):
            if relax(u, v) and v not in Q: #UPDATED
                Q.add(v) #UPDATED

def print_path_and_sum(): #updated

    l = []
    n = dest
    while n:
        l.append(n)
        n = parent.get(n)
    sum = 0
    while l:
        n = l.pop()
        sum += n[0]
        print(n)
    print(sum)

ar,sp=readfile("p081_matrix.txt")
source=(ar[0][0],0,0)
dest=(ar[79][79],79,79)
sp[source]=source[0]
Q=set() # updated
parent={}
dijkstra()
print_path_and_sum() #updated
print(sp[dest])
```

**A Different Solution**

```
def solve(matrix):
    MAX_N = len(matrix) - 1
    # do last row:
    for col in range(MAX_N - 1, -1, -1):
        matrix[MAX_N][col] += matrix[MAX_N][col + 1]
    # do remaining rows:
    for row in range(MAX_N - 1, -1, -1):
        for col in range(MAX_N, -1, -1):
            if col == MAX_N:
                matrix[row][col] += matrix[row + 1][col]
            else:
                matrix[row][col] += min(matrix[row][col+1], matrix[row + 1][col])
    return matrix[0][0]

matrix = []
with open('p081_matrix.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        matrix.append([int(n) for n in line.split(',')])
print(solve(matrix))
```

**Ad Different Solution With Path Information**

```
from copy import deepcopy

def solve(matrix):
    for row in range(MAX_N, -1, -1):
        for col in range(MAX_N, -1, -1):
            if row == MAX_N and col == MAX_N:
                continue
            if col == MAX_N:
                follow[(row, col)] = (row + 1, col)
                matrix[row][col] += matrix[row + 1][col]
            elif row == MAX_N:
                follow[(row, col)] = (row, col + 1)
                matrix[row][col] += matrix[row][col + 1]
            elif matrix[row][col+1] < matrix[row + 1][col]:
                follow[(row, col)] = (row, col + 1)
                matrix[row][col] += matrix[row][col + 1]
            else:
                follow[(row, col)] = (row + 1, col)
                matrix[row][col] += matrix[row + 1][col]
    return matrix[0][0]

def print_path_and_sum():
    sum = 0
    t = (0, 0)
    while t:
        v = matrix_copy[t[0]][t[1]]
        print(t, v)
        sum += v
        t = follow.get(t)
    print(sum)

matrix = []
with open('p081_matrix.txtt') as f:
    for line in f:
        matrix.append([int(n) for n in line.split(',')])
MAX_N = len(matrix) - 1
follow = {}
matrix_copy = deepcopy(matrix)
solution = solve(matrix)
print_path_and_sum()
print(solution)
```

Comment: Please take another look.

Answer (score 1):

This problem does not require a sophisticated tree search. The answer can be computed iteratively in a single pass.

Here is a simple solution that goes through the cells of the matrix from top to bottom and left to right accumulating the sums and selecting the smallest one based on the value computed for the cells above and to the left.  The first row and the first column are unconditional sums given that there is no alternate paths to go through.

```
from itertools import accumulate
def minSumPath(M):
    R = list(accumulate(M[0]))
    for row,values in enumerate(M[1:],1):
        R = [*accumulate((R[0]+values[0],*zip(R[1:],values[1:])),
                         lambda left,rv:min(left,rv[0])+rv[1])]   
    return R[-1]
           
M = [ [131, 673, 234, 103,  18],
      [201,  96, 342, 965, 150],
      [630, 803, 746, 422, 111],
      [537, 699, 497, 121, 956],
      [805, 732, 524,  37, 331]]

print(minSumPath(M)) # 2427
```

As the loops progresses R holds the the lowest sum path to each position on the previous row.  In the above example, R will progress as follows:

```
[131,  804,  1038, 1141, 1159]
[332,  428,   770, 1735, 1309]
[962,  1231, 1516, 1938, 1420]
[1499, 1930, 2013, 2059, 2376]
[2304, 2662, 2537, 2096, 2427]
```

the last value of the last row is the answer.

*Note that this approach could easily be adapted to use a row iterator as input. It would then be very memory efficient as it only needs to hold 2 rows of data to process the input file.*

You could also use a naive recursive approach where the result is obtained by computing the sum path of the cell above and to the left of the one at the bottom right corner.  Even with memoization, this is 60 times slower than the iterative solution above.  It is an interesting conceptual approach though:

```
from functools import lru_cache

def minSumPath(M):
    
    @lru_cache() # needs hashable (tuple) parameters
    def minSumPathT(T):
        if 1 in map(len,(T,T[0])): return sum(map(sum,T)) # single row or column
        fromAbove = minSumPathT(T[:-1])
        fromLeft  = minSumPathT(tuple(row[:-1] for row in T))
        return T[-1][-1] + min(fromAbove,fromLeft)
    
    return minSumPathT(tuple(map(tuple,M)))
```